# Remember state of uiswitch

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have an uiswitch in an app. If its on it writes in core data "yes" if its off it writes "no"

This is working now, but if I leave the view it off again.

```
-(IBAction)theSwitch {
    if (switchButton.on) {
        [self.detailItem setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"done"];

    } else {
        [self.detailItem setValue:@(NO) forKey:@"done"];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify that code to a one liner like this: `[self.detailItem setValue:@([switchButton isOn]) forKey:@"done"];`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt help me with my Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your viewDidLoad get your saved value from your detail item

```
theSwitch.on = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"done"] boolValue];
```

and for saving the Data Item (thanks to Dan Shelly)

```
NSError *saveError;
[self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save:&saveError]; // check if saveError is nil for error checking
```

Comment: Consider putting it in ViewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear. ViewDidLoad only gets called once in a view controller's lifetime. ViewDidAppear gets called every time it's shown (for example, switching between views).

Comment: It seems to work only on iphone… on ipad in split view it stays at on at all objects. If I change it there to on it stays at on.

Comment: are you sure you are saving it to your detailItem for ipad? look closer to your code, you must be skipping a save or load dialog somewhere.

Comment: I've checked the "done todo" as done and after taping on undone todo it was still there. In the database you can see, that it isnt marked as done. But it shows up like that… http://img.xnmn.de/i/2dae46.png

Comment: @Bartu mentioned saving. make sure to save your changes for them to be persistent (`[self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save:&error]`)

Comment: so you solved your issue? I have edited the answer according to Dan Shelly's addition